# How to check values inside foreach loop are same or not

Tags: php, arrays

i have a foreach loop as

```
foreach ($age as $ages) {
   echo $ages;
}
```

when run this code the result is

```
3
3
```

or

```
1
3
```

i want to check if values are same or not. For example

```
if (values are same) {
  do something...
}
else {
  do something...
}
```

i really couldn't find how to check values are same or not.

Comment: How many values need to be identical? 1? all?

Answer (score 0):

If you are checking to see if all values are identical just use `array_unique()` to remove duplicate values. Then check to see if the size of the remaining array is equal to 1:

```
$is_all_duplicates = count(array_unique($array)) === 1;
```

If any duplicates will trigger this condition, just use `array_unique()` to remove duplicate values and then compare the sizes of the two arrays. If they are not the same you had duplicate values:

```
$is_some_duplicates = count(array_unique($array)) < count($array);
```

Answer (score 0):

If values are the same, then `array_count_values` will have one element only:

```php
$a = [1,2,3,3];
$acv = array_count_values($a);
if (count($acv) == 1) {
    echo 'values are the same';
} else {
    echo 'values are NOT the same';
}


$a = [3,3,3];
$acv = array_count_values($a);
if (count($acv) == 1) {
    echo 'values are the same';
} else {
    echo 'values are NOT the same';
}
```

[The fiddle](https://3v4l.org/n6612).

But the most optimal solution is a simple loop with `break` on first value that is not equal to first of the array:

```php
$a = [1,2,3,3];
$hasSameValues = true;

$firstElem = array_slice($a, 0, 1)[0];
foreach ($a as $el) {
    if ($el != $firstElem) {
        $hasSameValues = false;
        break;
    }
}

if ($hasSameValues) {
    echo 'values are the same';
} else {
    echo 'values are NOT the same';
}

echo PHP_EOL;

$a = [3,3,3];
$hasSameValues = true;

$firstElem = array_slice($a, 0, 1)[0];
foreach ($a as $el) {
    if ($el != $firstElem) {
        $hasSameValues = false;
        break;
    }
}

if ($hasSameValues) {
    echo 'values are the same';
} else {
    echo 'values are NOT the same';
}
```

Yet another [fiddle](https://3v4l.org/YEpCg).

Answer (score 0):

You possible want to 'say' :)

```php
foreach ($ages as $age) {
   echo $age;
}
```

I understand that you want to check if only previous value is equal with actual value. 
To check that write this:

```php
$ages = [1,1,7,2,2,4,1,2];

foreach ($ages as $age) {
    if(isset($temp) ? !($temp == $age)  : true){
       echo $age;
    }
    $temp = $age;
}
```

The result is: 172412 
The code:
Check if variable `$temp` is set: `isset($temp)` 
If it is set, check if it is NOT equal with last age value: `!($temp == $age)`
If the `$temp` isn't set, set `true` to run the code from if statement (echo the age)(is there for first run).